# Unfortunately, myApplication has stopped

Tags: android, android-studio

Every time I run my App,it stops.

It says: `Unfortunately, myApplication has stopped`

how can i fix it?
I am using the latest version of Android Studio (1.5.x)

I named my application DDDx, as you can see in this screenshot

[image]

This is my log (part 1)

[image]

This is my log (part 2)

[image]

Comment: please put error stack/log

Comment: http://prntscr.com/977l7g
part 2
http://prntscr.com/977m08

(sorry for screenshots,i'm new in stackoverflow,i don't know if i can paste the whole log in code view)

Comment: Learn to read a Logcat. The line that says "caused by" is very important and usually tells you what you should look for.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: By the way, please also learn to post code and logcats as **text**, not as screenshots.

Comment: thanks
solved my problem :) 
sure will in sha Allah

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer. So you can accept it and remove this post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a `ListActivity`.
Therefore, in the Activity layout, you must have a **single** ListView with a **forced** id of `@android:id/list`.